# How do I establish a "test-port", through which selected private functions would be public?

Tags: typescript

Here's what I would *like*:

A utility type TestPorted such that with

```
class C {
  public p0() {
     return pv1() + this.pv2();
  }
  private pv1() {
    ...
  }
  private pv2() {
    ...
  }
}

type CT = TestPorted<CT, 'pv1', 'pv2'>;
```

would be the equivalent of

```
class CT {
  public p0() {
     return pv1() + this.pv2();
  }
  public testPort() {
     return {
        pv1: () => this.pv1(),
        pv2: () => this.pv2(),
     }
  }
  private pv1() {
    ...
  }
  private pv2() {
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm trying to establish a way for a class to export a subset of its private signature for the purposes of testing in a way that is clearly distinguishable from the class's public interface.

Look at any piece of commonly used complex equipment.  There is always some way for a trained technician to get more information about its internals than the less-trained operators.  Every car in the last 25 years has an OBD-II port; the driver doesn't know it's there but the mechanic does.

Obviously, this cannot be done purely with types, but I'm thinking some combination of types and a lodash-like functions could establish and obey a parallel test-only contract.

Comment: I suspect that would need e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22677 - currently you can only do that with `-readonly`. I guess it goes without saying that testing through private interfaces is generally discouraged.

Comment: @jonrsharpe — right now the categories of methods are "private" (only matters to the class), and "public" (part of the permanent signature); I'd like to add a third.